# Error CTC1014 Docker command failed with exit code 1 with dotnet core api

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I'm trying to build the most basic web Api application using VS2019 along with docker. Basically it is just the demo app provided by VS. I'm ending up with below error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CTC1014 Docker command failed with exit code 1.
>   hcsshim::PrepareLayer - failed failed in Win32: Incorrec

Below my `dockerfile`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1903 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-1903 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["RegexTesterApi/RegexTesterApi.csproj", "RegexTesterApi/"]
RUN dotnet restore "RegexTesterApi/RegexTesterApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/RegexTesterApi"
RUN dotnet build "RegexTesterApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "RegexTesterApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RegexTesterApi.dll"]
```

Well this is the auto generated `dockerfile`. But it looks pretty ok to me (also I'm new to docker).

What is actually causing the error.

Comment: Might not be too helpful but there an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3798) raised about this with a couple of purposed workarounds but nothing solid yet

Comment: If running from within Visual Studio 2019 the error console has an arrow `>` to the left of the error message; clicking this expands the error for a more detailed description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the very same error (CTC1014) in the past. I found out that my project was being run in "Release" mode, when it should have been running in "Debug" mode. So I would like to suggest this as **a workaround**.

[Here's how you change it in VS2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlIH0.png)

Of course, running your application in Release mode shouldn't be a problem. So I assumed it must have been related to some optimization employed by most release build configurations, in conflict with Docker. Not exactly sure which one, though.

Cheers! o/

Comment: Well, I still could not run it in neither release nor debug. Thing is it works with Linux container but not with windows

Comment: In my case, it had to do with the paths in the COPY and WORKDIR commands, which specified a leading "src/", which was not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue too, but with .net core 2.1. I'm not sure why it's working but, If this solution is available for you then try the following:

1. Restart Docker Desktop (This solution is offered in the output window)
2. Change the docker file.

I replaced this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:2.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:2.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
```

to

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.1-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /src
```

Then debug started to work fine even after changing the docker file to start variant, including stops on breakpoints. And my configuration has one additional difference:
I use Debug argument in the docker file and use Debug in Solution configuration

```
RUN dotnet build "DebugLinux.csproj" -c Debug -o /app/build
```

Answer (score 0):

This error migh be raised when the dockerfile in your project don't match the Target Framework in the project settings.

Just delete your dockerfile and create a new one and this will fix the problem if this is the issue.